# Error... Talk is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a small RPG game. 
But I keep receiving this error. I have my function (talk) defined. (activated by the talk button) Yet it says it's not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>

    </head>
    <title> </title>
    <body>
<script>

        function talk() {
                document.querySelector(".options").innerHTML = "<button onclick="fine()">I'm fine.</button>";
                }
    </script>
    <div class="options">
    <button onclick="talk()">Try it</button>
    <button onclick="silent()">Stay Silent</button>
    </div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the use of single and double quotation. Here's the fix:

```
function talk() {
    document.querySelector(".options").innerHTML = "<button onclick='fine()'>I'm fine.</button>";
}
```

After doing this you'll get "fine is not defined". So you'll need to do something like this:

```
function fine(){
    alert('I am fine');
}
```

Anyway, I don't get why are you trying to do this, but hope it helps!